# QTextEdit word blocks and text formatting

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I need to make a QLineEdit with non-editable word blocks.

For instance, imagine I drop a *word* (that actually represents a *value*) in a QLineEdit.
I would like to write normally on the QLineEdit, *BUT* if I try to move the cursor inside a *word* it would move over it, ie, place the cursor at the end/begining of the *word*.

Also, I would like the word to always show a certain highlight over it, with different colors (to emulate a box that would wrap it).

Any ideas on how to do this? Would a QTextArea be better for this? I was thinking of a QLineEdit because it would actually be inside a QTableWidget cell, so I think it may have more or less the same capabilities, am I wrong?

**UPDATE** I found these two functions that actually might be helpful for QLineEdit: [`cursorWordBackward()`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlineedit.html#cursorWordBackward) and [`cursorWordForward()`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlineedit.html#cursorWordBackward), so this might help move over the words. Anyone has examples of this?

**UPDATE 2** As QLineEdit does not support rich-text, the "highlight" feature I required can only be achieved with a QTextEdit. This has other issues: QTextEdit does not have the functions I mentioned in the first update above, and I don't know if it is possible to put a QTextEdit inside a QTableWidget cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLineEdit can contain only plain text and certainly can't do this. I was thinking about QTextEdit, it can display HTML. But looking at [the documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/richtext-html-subset.html), I realized that there is no way to insert non-editable block in QTextDocument (which is used by QTextEdit). I think there is no simple solution.

You can try to implement it manually. Catch `textChanged()` and `cursorPositionChanged()` signals of `QTextEdit`, analyze its content and cursor position and modify them if user moved the cursor into non-editable block or changed its content.

Comment: STOP FOLLOWING ME! :) jk, Good advice, actually, thank you! Can I create a QTextEdit inside a QTableWidget cell? Is it _dirty_?

Comment: I'm following Qt tag, not you :) Yes, you can attach custom editor to QTableWidget using `QItemDelegate`. See [Color Editor Factory Example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/itemviews-coloreditorfactory.html).

Comment: I was looking at the documentation as well, and I think I can actually use the `<span>` tag and use it as a _wrapper_ of sorts around my word - this would allow for highlight/formatting. But then I could use simply the _plain text_ to test with the signals you mentioned. What do you think? Is it possible to read the same content of the QTextEdit either as plain or rich-text?

Comment: And just now I saw the `toPlainText()` and the `toHtml()` functions... :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could achieve this by using an [inputMask](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop)...

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you elaborate? As I understand, this only allows me to define what can or can't be written in the QLineEdit, right?

Comment: @Joum: You could put your special word into the mask like "xxxxwor\dxxxx", but this might not look like you want and only works for a fixed input size before and after the word.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I can tell you that this isn't a valid option. I can' anticipate what the _word_ will be, so the mask would have to be dynamic. Plus, apparently, QLineEdit can't handle rich text and that by itself renders it useless for the "highlight" feature I required. Of course, I didn't know that when I asked the question, so I'll change the title as well.